# How to load a string into a C method using RubyInline

Tags: c, ruby, inline

I would like to use a C method in Ruby to work on a string. I have found a previous question on here that partly answered this.
I have used this gist to start my attempt: https://gist.github.com/dimus/147023.
It starts by trying to force the ruby string into an C array of ints.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'inline'

class TestC
  inline do |builder|

    builder.c "
      static
      void
      load_string(VALUE _s) {
        VALUE *sv = RARRAY_PTR(_s);
        int sl = RARRAY_LEN(_s);
        int s[sl];
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < sl; i++) {
          s[i] = NUM2INT(sv[i]);
        }
      }
    "
  end

  def run_inline
    load_string("string")
  end

end

test = TestC.new

test.run_inline
```

Unfortunately the line inside the for loop makes the code seg fault.

Has anyone used RubyInline recently? I am using Ruby 2.0.0p451.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C code you call `VALUE *sv = RARRAY_PTR(_s);`, so you are treating the parameter as a Ruby array, but you call it with `load_string("string")` – i.e. you pass a string. The pointer you get is therefore invalid and when you try to use it you get the segfault.

If you pass in an array (e.g. `load_string(["string"])` you will fix the segfault, but this will generate `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` when you try to use `NUM2INT` on the string.

You will need to make sure you check the types of the parameters to the method, and handle the case when the type is not what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have strlen +1 large buffer to store. +1 is for null.

try `int s[sl+1];`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in the end:

```
static
void
string_parse(VALUE _s) {
  int i,sl,longest=0;
  char * c_str;

  sl = RSTRING_LEN(_s);
  c_str = StringValueCStr(_s);
  for (i=0;i<sl;i++) {
    // do stuff here
  }

  return INT2NUM(longest);
}
```